# Facebook integration, Website with a Business Page(not profile)

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, integration

Is the following possible, after many hours of searching I cannot find a straight answer anywhere.

From an external website, which users login to using their Facebook Login, we wish to allow users to upload photos to a Facebook Page of which we are the administrators.
The photos should go to a specific album which we will create.
Photos can be uploaded as either Administrator or by the actual id of the user logged in, would prefer logged in Id but that doesnt seem possible so the page admin details can be used for authentication within the code if it makes this possible.

This external site is .Net (C#)

I have googled and some people say the photos get uploaded the users own profile, an album in there. Instead of the Page. Others say it should be possible but dont say how or if they have infact done it so really hoping someone has actual experience in doing this so i know if its a possibility and will not be spending days trying to do something that will never work.

Answer (score 7):

Face book now have its new API called Graph API.In this API you will get the option for image uploading into album.Please go through  the link

[Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

Hope its work.

Comment: The API makes reference to user profiles not a Page. I need to upload to an Album on a Fan Page for example that i am the administrator of.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the photo album yet, however, look at the following:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

From there you will have to setup an application and see if the .api has the ability to upload photos to your application photo album.

Although I have not used this feature, I did a quick search on the link above for photo uploads and came up with this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload

Hope that helps.